# Let's get critical: Oct 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Biology Stack Exchange](http://biology.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://biology.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can the colour of skin change with age](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10082/can-the-colour-of-skin-change-with-age)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Are there specific conditions that allow humans to see ultraviolet wavelengths](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9976/are-there-specific-conditions-that-allow-humans-to-see-ultraviolet-wavelengths)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [copper vs aluminum, what's the safest for health?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9902/copper-vs-aluminum-whats-the-safest-for-health)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [What is the advantage of the way eukaryotes initiate translation?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9991/what-is-the-advantage-of-the-way-eukaryotes-initiate-translation)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [How did viruses learn to utilize the workings of a cell?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/how-did-viruses-learn-to-utilize-the-workings-of-a-cell)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What is the evidence that australopithecines were bipedal?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/9791/what-is-the-evidence-that-australopithecines-were-bipedal)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Tree census data for Sweden/Scandinavia?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10037/tree-census-data-for-sweden-scandinavia)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Why do we have no enzyme to digest cellulose?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10265/why-we-have-no-enzyme-to-digest-cellulose)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Is there any advantage of having a mitochondria for aerobic respiration?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10277/is-there-any-advantage-of-having-a-mitochondria-for-aerobic-respiration)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Eating rarely but a lot, or often but little](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10176/eating-rarely-but-a-lot-or-often-but-little)

  **Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 6)